# Read .DER value from GCP secret manager and save it to .DER file

Tags: database, spring-boot, ssl, google-cloud-platform

At first, its my first post - sorry if this post is not vell described and designed.

My problem is that i need to connect to DB in GCP by SSL connection using spring boot. Inside GCP im generating three needed certs(client-cert.pem, client-key.pem, server-ca.pem). Unfortunately spring cannot connect to db with client-key stored in pem file, so i have to keep client-key for exmaple inside .DER cert.

To connect to db i use this piece of code.

```
return DataSourceBuilder
                .create()
                .url("jdbc:postgresql://XXX:5432/XXX?" +
                        "ssl=true&sslmode=verify-ca&" +
                        "sslrootcert=server-ca.pem&" +
                        "sslcert=client-cert.pem&" +
                        "sslkey=client-key.der")
                .build();
    }
```

To generate .DER from .PEM file i used this command:

```
openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -inform PEM -in client-key.pem -outform DER -nocrypt -out client-key.der
```

Locally its working, but i have to keep certs inside secret manager(SM) at GCP. SM can store only values so i keep binary values from .DER file

```
![Take a look at image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dAjLU.png).
```

Im using GCP java libriaries to connect to SM:

```
 private String getKey(String projectId, String secretCertName, boolean isPEM) {
            try (SecretManagerServiceClient client = SecretManagerServiceClient.create()) {
                SecretVersionName secretVersionName = SecretVersionName.of(projectId, secretCertName, "latest");
                AccessSecretVersionResponse response = client.accessSecretVersion(secretVersionName);
                return response.getPayload().getData().toStringUtf8();
                
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("gcp cant connect !");
            }
            return null;
    }
```

Its working with PEM and string values, but if i want save this key inside .DER file then my client-key.der file is not matching to cert generated by openssl and spring cant connect to DB with stack:

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Could not read SSL key file client-key.der. at org.postgresql.ssl.LazyKeyManager.getPrivateKey(LazyKeyManager.java:284) ~[postgresql-42.3.2.jar:42.3.2] at java.base/sun.security.ssl.AbstractKeyManagerWrapper.getPrivateKey(SSLContextImpl.java:1696) ~[na:na] ...

> Caused by: java.io.IOException: Invalid lenByte at java.base/sun.security.util.DerValue.<init>(DerValue.java:374) ~[na:na] at java.base/sun.security.util.DerValue.<init>(DerValue.java:312) ~[na:na] at java.base/javax.crypto.EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo.<init>(EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo.java:86) ~[na:na] at org.postgresql.ssl.LazyKeyManager.getPrivateKey(LazyKeyManager.java:236) ~[postgresql-42.3.2.jar:42.3.2] ... 73 common frames omitted

Any idea how I should read binary files ( like .DER cert ) from GCP SM ? I read that should be encoded, but i have had no success until now.

Thanks for advance and please be gentle, its my first post :)

Comment: Base64 encode and then insert into Secret Manager. Base64 decode after reading a secret. DER is a binary format. By base64 encoding, you convert binary to strings.

Comment: my mistake was trying to saving String to file instead of byte[] ...
Its working, thank you!

Comment: @goloneczka, Welcome to stackoverflow. Since your issue is resolved can you post the procedure you've followed as Solution and accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basing on John comment i saved encoded .DER file inside secret manager. Next i decoded value from secret manager API. Important thing in this case - save byte[] instead of String, to file !

UPDATE:
you needen't save encoded .DER values inside SM. You can keep there binary values, but to get these values from API you need use:

```
return response.getPayload().getData().toByteArray();
```

and to save inside .DER cert then use this lines:

> try (FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(path)) {
> stream.write(Base64.getMimeDecoder().decode(Base64.getEncoder().encode(certValue)));
> }